# How to call a powershell function from a variable

Tags: xml, function, powershell

I want to create a function to call a function with parameters and output the results of the called function.

Working Code:

```
$MockDataPath = 'C:\temp'
$MockDataFunctionName = 'Get-SomeFunction'
$Results = Get-SomeFunction -Parameter1 'SomeParameter'
$Results | Export-CliXML "$MockDataPath\$MockDataFunctionName.xml"
```

What I want to do:  The first `$Results =` line is where I'm having the issue.  I know it does not work but I have been unable to find a solution online.  I'm also unsure if the `$MockFunctionParameters` is the correct approach for parameter passing.

```
Function Get-MockedData {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param(
    [Parameter(
      Position = 0,
      Mandatory = $true,
      ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true,
      HelpMessage = "Enter the name of the function you want to get mock data from.  Ex: Get-GenericCredential")]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [string]
    $MockFunctionName,

    [Parameter(
      Mandatory = $false,
      ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true,
      HelpMessage = "Enter the parameters of the function you want to get mock data from.  Ex: '-Parameter1 SomeParameter'")]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [string]
    $MockFunctionParameters,

    [Parameter(
      Mandatory = $false,
      ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true,
      HelpMessage = "Enter the directory you want the mocked data to appear.  Default: 'C:\temp'")]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [string]
    $MockDataOutputPath = 'C:\temp'
  )

  $Results = $MockFunctionName $MockFunctionParameters
  $Results | Export-Clixml "$MockDataOutputPath\$MockDataFunctionName.xml"
}
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting? If the function is present in different file, are you loading the module or the function itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going to need to use Splatting rather than passing the parameters as a string.  So you'd call it as `Get-MockedData -MockFunctionName <name> -MockFunctionParameters @{Parameter1 = "SomeParameter}`

Then you call the function in `$Result` using `&`.

```
$Results = &$MockFunctionName @MockFunctionParameters
```

Bruce Payette pointed out that `Invoke-Expression` is considered harmful (and in this case could result in injection because you're passing arbitrary parameters and functions).

---

Alternately, you can use DynamicParameters and actually have it include the parameters from the original function (Which will still work with splatting as above but also allows clearer functionality when using interactively).

It doesn't have full functionality but does offer tab completion for parameters (it has a few issues there such as `get-content` not showing `-path` but completing `-pa<tab>` into `-path`) although it will not always offer tab completion with `ValidationSet` (It works on a custom function but failed on `New-Item -itemtype` so it might be an issue with built-in commands).  It does not need `-MockFunctionParameters` since those parameters can be splatted (`$splat = @{path = "test.xml"}`) directly in to the function call `Get-MockedData get-content @splat`.

```powershell
function Get-MockedData {
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(
            Position = 0,
            Mandatory = $true,
            ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true,
            HelpMessage = "Enter the name of the function you want to get mock data from.  Ex: Get-GenericCredential")]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [ValidateScript( {Get-Command $_})]
        [string]
        $MockFunctionName,

        [Parameter(
            Mandatory = $false,
            ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true,
            HelpMessage = "Enter the directory you want the mocked data to appear.  Default: 'C:\temp'")]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]
        $MockDataOutputPath = 'C:\temp'
    )
    DynamicParam {
        if ($MockFunctionName) {
            $base = get-command $MockFunctionName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        }
        if ($base) {
            $dict = new-object System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameterDictionary
            $base.Parameters.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {
                $val = $_.value
                $key = $_.key
                if ($key -notin [System.Management.Automation.Internal.CommonParameters].GetProperties().name) {
                    $param = New-Object System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameter($key, $val.parameterType, $val.attributes)
                    $dict.add($key, $param)
                }
            }
            return $dict
        }
    }
    Begin {
        # Get a list of own parameters to exclude later
        $self = Get-Command Get-MockedData
        $selfParams = $self.parameters.keys | Where-Object {
            $_ -notin [System.Management.Automation.Internal.CommonParameters].GetProperties().name -and
            -not $self.parameters.$_.isdynamic
        }
    }
    Process {
        # Hashtable to hold valid parameters
        $splatParams = @{}

        # Remove own parameters
        $psboundparameters.keys | where-object {$_ -notin $selfParams} | ForEach-Object {
            $splatParams.add($_, $psboundparameters[$_])
        }

        $results = &$MockFunctionName @splatParams
        $Results | Export-Clixml "$MockDataOutputPath\$MockDataFunctionName.xml"
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm - splatting is the right answer but `Invoke-Expression` is not splatting. It evaluates strings as code which is not want you want here.  Use the call operator with splatting to get the desired results: `$Results = & $MockFunctionName @MockFunctionParameters`

Comment: Actually splatting does work in `iex` (just tested to be sure).  Simply forgot to actually include the splat in the call rather than the variable name.

Comment: Yes - with the @ it does work but using `iex` is strongly discouraged. If you haven't, please read Jason's post from a while back "Invoke Expression Considered Harmful"  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/

Comment: I'd seen that before.  I'd just somehow mixed up which of the two used a subscope rather than ran in parent scope (for injection purposes).  Answer updated to use `&` rather than `iex` because of that

Comment: Awesome! Thanks.

Comment: @BrucePayette Added in an alternate solution that simplifies the actual invocation by using dynamic parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the call operator `&` to indirectly call a function. In the second last line of your function put '&' before `$MockFunctionName` as in

```
  $Results = & $MockFunctionName $MockFunctionParameters
```

Parameters are trickier - there you should look at [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-6) to see how to pass parameters.

Finally, you might want to look at how [Pester](https://github.com/pester/Pester) handles [mocking](https://github.com/pester/Pester/wiki/Mocking-with-Pester).